# Computing $\int_{0}^{1} x \ln(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}) dx$

Tags: calculus

I need some help evaluating the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} x \ln(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}) dx$$

What came to mind was doing $1 + x^2 = t$ substitution and finally that got me to
$$\frac{1}{2} (t \ln(1+\sqrt{t}) - \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{2(1+\sqrt{t})}dt ) $$
(changed the limits of integration)

However, I don't know how to compute that last integral.
$$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+\sqrt{t}} dt $$

Doing the substitution 
$$ \sqrt{t} = x $$
$$ t = x^2 $$
$$ dt = 2xdx $$

leads me to

$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{2x^2}{x+1}dx $$

And now I'm stuck again.

Comment: Remember to change the limits when you change variables.

Comment: The limits of integration will change once you have made the substitution $1+x^2=t$. You could make another substitution: $u=1+\sqrt{t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can divide to get $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{2x^2}{x+1}\;dx=2\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(x-1+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\;dx$

---

Notice that you could also have started by letting $t=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ to get
$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}t\ln(1+t)\;dt$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+\sqrt{t}} dt\stackrel{t=x^2}\longrightarrow\int\frac{2x^2}{1+x}dx\stackrel{y=x+1}\longrightarrow\int\frac{2(y-1)^2}{y}dy$$
Expand and integrate!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the substitution $u = 1+\sqrt{t}$ with $du = \frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}} \implies dt = 2(u-1)du$. Hence, $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+\sqrt{t}} dt = 2\int_1^2 \frac{(u-1)^2}{u}du \\ = 2\int_1^2 u-2+\frac{1}{u}\space  du$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the substitute $u=\sqrt{t}$.